# Conditional formatting of a Datasheet Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

i have a datasheet form in MS Access 2010.
this form is connected to a table.
it has three fields and the first and second fields have common words in them.
WHen the form Displays I want the cells with common words between the two column to Display in green.
i am trying with conditional formatting but it just does not seem to work..
can it be done programatically?

Comment: You *can* do conditional formatting with datasheet forms. Please show a screenshot or your current formatting rule, and some sample data.

Comment: yes, i could do it now. But now I have another Problem. The Table is connected to a subform which is in a Pop up form. I did the conditional formatting to the subform and it works. No Problem. But when I open the Pop up form all the formatting disappears and there are no Colors visible. Is there something that I have to activate or Change. I tried with .REPAINT and .SETFOCUS.. but no success.